# How to style a text wrapping (hanging, like in MS Word) in the WPF TextBlock

Tags: wpf, styles, word-wrap

I need to style a WPF TextBlock, like

```
<TextBlock Text="- Test text text text text" TextWrapping="Wrap"/>
```

that will show the

```
- Test text text text 
  text
```

and not the

```
- Test text text text 
text
```

Do you know the solution of the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you need to apply advanced local formatting to your text you'd better use a **RichTextBox** that will offer you more control.

Comment: unfortunally, this is not an equivalent replacement of the TextBlock, especially if you need a flexible binding.

Comment: What do you mean by "a flexible binding"? A RichTextBox IS more flexible, since it allows you to customize every single char in you text...

Answer (score 0):

Can you split it in 2 TextBlocks: one with **"- "**, the 2nd with **"Test text text text text"** ? That way you would achieve what you ask.

(haha :) , just saw : asked 5 years ago )

Comment: Surely, the text can be placed in 2 containers, but the question was how to style the existing TextBlock.